# how can I get rails_admin to handle associations properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Two questions:

1) How can I make a column in the 'list' for a model consist of data from the record's association? In other words, I have a user model and a user has_many posts. I want to simply have a "post count" column in the list. I tried doing:

```
field :posts do
  formatted_value do
    value.count
  end
end
```

but that results in a divide by zero error. I even tried doing:

```
field :posts do
  formatted_value do
    bindings[:object].posts.count
  end
end
```

but got the same results.

2) How can I filter the listing to a particular scope? For example, I want to make the users post count be a link that is clickable which will show all posts for the given user.

The best I could figure out how to do this was to do:

```
# note that I created a method post_count to temporarily solve problem #1
field :post_count do
  formatted_value do
    bindings[:view].link_to value, "/admin/posts?query=#{bindings[:object].id}"
  end
end
```

Which doesn't work very well. Is there a way to instruct rails-admin to do a `.where(:user_id => xxx)` on the model?

The other thing I wasn't crazy about was having to manually put in 'admin/posts'.. I was trying to see if I could do `rails_admin_list_path(:model_name => "posts")`. but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably get a better response on the rails_admin mailing list - http://groups.google.com/group/rails_admin/

For your first question, this should do the trick:

```
field :posts, :virtual do
  formatted_value do
    bindings[:object].posts.count
  end
end
```

For your second question, rails_admin now has a filter system - see the "add filter" dropdown at http://demo.railsadmin.org/admin/players . Tapping into that would be a much better method.

`rails_admin_list_path(:model_name => "posts")` should work, you might have to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :field_name}
```

worked for me